# Select maximum id in each series

Tags: mysql

I need to select min and max ID in each number series "c_protokolu" in table similar to this. There are deletes from the table, so some IDs are missing.

| id | c_protokolu | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2021-06-22 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-08-14 |
| 3 | 2 | 2022-01-06 |
| 4 | 0 | 2022-07-12 |
| 8 | 1 | 2022-09-09 |

I have come up if that, which works, but isn't very readable.

```
SELECT 
    id,
    IFNULL((SELECT 
                    (SELECT 
                                MAX(id)
                            FROM
                                vody v3
                            WHERE
                                v3.id < v2.id
                            LIMIT 1)
                FROM
                    vody v2
                WHERE
                    v2.id > v1.id AND c_protokolu = 0
                ORDER BY id ASC
                LIMIT 1),
            (SELECT 
                    MAX(id)
                FROM
                    vody v4)) AS max_id
FROM
    vody v1
WHERE
    c_protokolu = 0
```

Hopefully there is a better, simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks only marginally better.

> ```
> WITH CTE as 
> (SELECT MAX(id) max_,MIN(id) min_ FROm vody WHERE c_protokolu = 0)
> SELECT min_ as id,(SELECT id FROM vody WHERE id < max_ ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) max_id FROM CTE
> UNION
> SELECT max_,(SELECT MAX(id) FROM vody) FROM CTE
> ```

> ```
> id | max_id
> -: | -----:
>  1 |      3
>  4 |      8
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a656af6bc6c69fffcd08607079eb41ca)*

> ```
> SELECT min_ as id,(SELECT id FROM vody WHERE id < max_ ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) max_id FROM (SELECT
> MIN(id) min_,MAX(id) max_  FROm vody WHERE c_protokolu = 0) CTE
> UNION
> SELECT max_,(SELECT MAX(id) FROM vody) FROM (SELECT
> MAX(id) max_ FROm vody WHERE c_protokolu = 0) CTE
> ```

> ```
> id | max_id
> -: | -----:
>  1 |      3
>  4 |      8
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=3084e7d5e6fed09f5f43706d1db40adf)*

Comment: Unfortunately when trying your solution, i found out that production DB has mariadb version 5.1.73 in which this solution doesnt work.

Comment: @Yon it is no problem CTE are only a suplement for subqueries and make the code somewhat more organized, so you can change it easily